# Defining an infinitely nested HashMap in Rust

Tags: rust, types

I'm trying to represent a file directory structure in Rust, and the way I'm doing it is through a nested hashmap. My idea is to have a type that looks like this:

```rust
HashMap<&'a str, HashMap<&'a str, HashMap<&'a str, ...>>>
```

However that's impossible to type in Rust. I need to wrap the HashMap in a struct to be able to type it:

```rust
struct Node<'a> {
    children: HashMap<&'a str, Rc<Node<'a>>>,
}
```

However, creating a struct containing a single field seems wasteful to me. Is there any way to achieve the first example without creating a struct?

Comment: I don't see how a single field struct would be wasteful, so called newtype structs are a zero cost abstraction.

Comment: Bonus: if you use `#[repr(transparent)]` it's guarenteed to be exactly the same as the inner structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.  Infinitely-recursive generics are not supported in Rust.

The newtype (single-field struct) approach is not wasteful, and is in fact idiomatic Rust.  You may be used to other languages where each level of nesting creates a level of indirection and a new heap allocation, but that's not how Rust works; the size of `Node<'a>` and the size of `HashMap<&'a str, Rc<Node<'a>>>` [will be identical](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1551a506d0721e315f0324310e6d0f58) because structs directly contain their fields.

My only suggestion would be to consider whether you *really* need reference counting in this structure.  If not, you can remove the `Rc` layer entirely, which effectively gives you a type with the same conceptual memory layout as the hypothetical infinitely-recursive type.